# Ordinary differential equation for disease modelling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

On the first day of school after a break, one student comes to school having been infected with the flu virus. There are 100 students in the school. The rate of the spread of the flu virus in the school can be modelled by ${dN\over dt}= kN(100-N)$, where N is the number of students infected after $t$ days.

The solution to this differential equation is $Ae^{100kt}$= ${N\over 100-N}$.

I got $N(100-N)$ and $dN$ to one side and and $dt$ and 100k to the other side. I could integrate the $dN$ side to get ${N\over 100-N}$; however, I think I am wrong to bring $100k$ with $dt$ as I only did it to get the final answer. I'm not so sure how I could get the answer as the solution provided to the differential equation.

Comment: $\dfrac1{N(100-N)}=\dfrac1{100}\left(\dfrac1N+\dfrac1{100-N}\right)$

Comment: Don't delete your question immediately after receiving an answer. It's unkind to those who take the time to answer your questions and it makes is appear as though you are trying to hide something.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thanks for the feedback. I was able to work out the answer and so decided to delete the question and replace it with another. I understand though and I'll make sure to be more mindful of this next time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a separable differential equation:

$${dN\over dt} = kN(100-N)$$

$$\int\dfrac{dN}{N(100-N)}=\int k dt$$

$$\dfrac1{100}(\ln N - \ln (100-N))=kt+C$$

$$\dfrac{N}{100-N}=Ae^{100kt}$$